# Permanently allow localhost server urls

Tags: server, localhost

Is there a way to permanently allow localhost server urls

[image]

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: i use brave browser.

Comment: As you are trying to use HTTPS, the browser is validating the HTTPS certificate against the server name (which is 'localhost'). Does you certificate relate to 'localhost'? Is it a valid certificate? There are various hits on the web for 'how to create a certificate for localhost'.